# Issue with DocsList.getFolder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I have a script using getFolder as follows:

```
DocsList.getFolder("RDV/2013")
```

It was working perfectly till this morning.

Now `DocsList.getFolder("RDV")` works OK, but as soon as I add `("RDV/2013")` I get an error saying that "2013" doesn't exist which of course is not the case.

I've tried with other sub-folders and get the same error result.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: I would start by using the Drive service which is more robust, newer and not "experimental'.  DriveApp.getFoldersByName(name) would be the call to make ... you can also look at the iterator to traverse the contents of the Drive as needed.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the tip. I've tried your solution but doesn't seem to take a path like ("RDV/2013") into account but just a folder single name. I've seen the issue on DocsList.getFolder [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2115) For now my workaround uses the DocsList.getFolderById().

Comment: Yes you can not use path, you should either iterate through, of get all folders with "2013" and check the results to find the proper parent folder.  If you know which folder it is at programming time, I guess its safer to find out the id and get the folder by id, so even if it gets renamed by mistake you are in the clear.

Comment: Yes I'm in this situation but it's not entirely satisfying. Don't understand why Google is stuck with this bug for so long. Tanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In a very quick test with the following code:

```js
function getFolder() {
  var folder = DocsList.getFolder('RDV/2013');
  Logger.log(folder.getName()); // 2013
}
```

I can not reproduce the error, everything works as expected.

The recommendation is to use [DriveApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app), but it lacks a method like `.getFolder(String path)`

Comment: Yes it was working fine for me as well before today. But as said [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2115) this bug is known for a while and not solved yet.

Comment: @Manutara The test script was created today, but the error appears to be random. In all my attempts I could not reproduce the problem.